# Self-avoiding walks from one diagonal to the other on $mxn$ lattice is ${m+n \choose m,n} $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) "self-avoiding walks from one end of a diagonal to the other, with only moves in the positive direction, there are exactly
$$ 
\binom{n+m}{n,m}
$$paths for an $m × n$ rectangular lattice.

I don't understand how this holds. For example m = 1, n = 3 then 
$$\binom{1+3}{1,3} = 4 $$. How are there 4 walks on a 1x3 lattice?

Aren't these walks the same as self-avoiding rook walks?

Comment: The title is misleading, or perhaps reflects a misunderstanding of the "self-avoiding walk" described in the Wikipedia article.  The walk is from one "corner" of the lattice to the opposing corner, where coordinates never decrease by any steps, and some coordinate increases in each step.  In terms of a rook walk, the size would have to increase by one in each dimension to accomodate the difference between a rook sitting in a square and positions located at vertices of a lattice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean a lattice in which $m$ vertical and $n$ horizontal steps can be taken, that is, $m+1$ rows and $n+1$ columns of grid points that surround $m$ rows and $n$ columns of squares.